# Casablanca tutorial not working on my Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, casablanca

I have a problem with [Casablanca](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/).

I have installed it on my Linux Ubuntu x64: no errors; and run all the tests: all passed. I have done it like on the [linux install support page](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20Linux&referringTitle=Documentation), but I have installed the latest libraries.

I copied the [tutorial](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http%20Client%20Tutorial) code from their site, and when I run it, it says:

```
*** Crashed with return code: 0 ***
```

If I run it in debug, I see that it crashes on the line

```
return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
```

If I do it another way:

```
http_request request;

request.set_request_uri(builder.to_uri());

request.set_method(methods::GET);

try {
  client.request(request);
} catch(std::exception e) {
  std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

it crashes at `client.request(request);` from try block and it still says

```
*** Crashed with return code: 0 ***
```

so there is no error / exception

I suppose more possible problems:

- The libraries shall be exactly the ones that you specify?
- Could it be the `methods::GET` the problem? I do not think so, but it says that it cannot find the declaration of it. Not as a warning, or error, but it is underlined with yellow and it shows this message when I put the mouse over it.

I have read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336259/c-rest-sdk-casablanca-client-request) but its answer is also not working.

1. Could it be a bug?
2. Could it be something on my machine?

Comment: Could you include the line where you construct the http_client object client?